# GPT2 input size with wiki articles

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use a small pre-trained GPT2 model on wikipedia text. I try to use as much text as I can as the input for the gpt2 model. The model summarizes the text for me. How do I use the whole wiki article for input. As it is now I'm limited to something like 768 tokens. A typical wiki article is longer than that. Is there a trick to using text passages longer than 768 tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.

But one thing you need to keep in mind that the `input_shape` of the model remains the same and so you have to specify the `maximum` sequence length you want give input to the model.

**And now coming back to what you can do -**

If you change the input of the model, the input shape of the subsequent layer also changes.

What you can do is you can copy the model architecture along with its pretrained weights and fine-tune it with the desired input shape. It does not matter whether you are using PyTorch or any other framework. Only the `input_shape` changes as per your requirement. PyTorch saves the model weights in an `OrderedDict`, you can load the pretrained model and copy the weights from there.

*Sample:*

```
model1 = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model1.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH_TO_PRETRAINED_MODEL))
model1.eval()

model2 = TheNewModelClass(*args, **kwargs)

params1 = model1.named_parameters()
params2 = model2.named_parameters()

dict_params2 = dict(params2)

for name1, param1 in params1:
    if name1 in dict_params2:
        dict_params2[name1].data.copy_(param1.data)
```

You can find some good reference links in the PyTorch Forum here:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/copying-weights-from-one-net-to-another/1492

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/copy-weights-only-from-a-networks-parameters/5841

Comment: I'm using pytorch. It sounds to me like you're saying it cannot be done. I don't want to change the model at all.

Comment: Hi! It does not matter whether your are using PyTorch or any other framework. I am not telling you to change the model at all. The whole architecture remains the same. Only the input changes as per your requirement. PyTorch saves the model weights in an `OrderedDict`, you can load the model and copy the weights from there.

Comment: If you have further doubts in copying weights, I can help you out with that also. Feel free to drop a comment below.